# jQuery element inconsistently having access to a function

Tags: jquery, dom

I am using the Orchard CMS Contoso theme which came with this nifty built-in slideshow scripting:

```
<p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Themes/Contoso/Scripts/easySlider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#slider").easySlider({
                prevText: '',
                nextText: '',
                speed: '1600',
            });
        });
        // ]]>
    </script>
</p>
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="~~~~~" alt="~~~~~" /></li>
        <li><img src="~~~~~" alt="~~~~~" /></li>
        <li><img src="~~~~~" alt="~~~~~" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[source](http://cssglobe.com/jquery-plugin-easy-image-or-content-slider/)

However, when copying this markup into another page (I want it located in a different portion of the page), I get an uncaught "Object [object Object] has no method 'easySlider'" exception.

Both pages have access to the same source files, is it possible that the different wrapping elements (they have CSS classes attached to them) could be the issue?  It doesn't appear in the documentation but I don't know what else could be causing the issue.

This is the relevant CSS in Site.css (which is applied to both pages)

```
#slider ul, #slider li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#slider, #slider li { 
    /* 
        define width and height of container element and list item (slide)
        list items must be the same size as the slider area
    */ 
    width:471px;
    height:319px;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Comment: No, it's going to be related to the order in which jQuery and said plugin are included. Something is most likely overriding `$` with something other than jQuery.

Comment: Use Google Console to see if the /Themes/Contoso/Scripts/easySlider.js is loading correctly on that 2nd page.

Comment: Putting a breakpoint on the function declaration indicated it is being loaded correctly, but the buttons that interact with the slideshow are never causing me to enter the function body.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your issue, but it should help.

1.// Since you're using a CMS, your jquery instance "$" may be overwritten. Avoid it by using $.noconflict();

2.// **Structure your html markup correctly**: If you are going to use several sliders on the same page, use classes instead of ids, and put all of your javascript at the bottom of the page (slow connection users will thank you for that).

So instead of writing

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="~~~~~" alt="~~~~~" /></li>
        <li><img src="~~~~~" alt="~~~~~" /></li>
        <li><img src="~~~~~" alt="~~~~~" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

do

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="~~~~~" alt="~~~~~" /></li>
        <li><img src="~~~~~" alt="~~~~~" /></li>
        <li><img src="~~~~~" alt="~~~~~" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then, include all javascript right before the closing body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Themes/Contoso/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Themes/Contoso/Scripts/easySlider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
$.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".slider").easySlider({
                prevText: '',
                nextText: '',
                speed: '1600',
            });
        });
        // ]]>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This eliminated the error for me but the slideshow is still broken (DOM rendered the same).  No errors get thrown when clicking the slideshow buttons.  It seems I am unable to enter the function body.

EDIT: Also this is the only element on the page with this Id so there should be no conflicts.

Comment: please post a jsfiddle.net prototype or the url to your page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5MkRX/3/

Had to change some things around since they were local resources, but this is more or less what I have on my page without the loaded image sources.  The previous button can be a little difficult to see since it is floating outside the panel.

Comment: I accidentally hit "update" instead of "fork" so you may want to resubmit your changes but I modified the CSS to match my current CSS (updated the ul's and the li's to ignore overflow):  http://jsfiddle.net/5MkRX/5/

Forked: http://jsfiddle.net/Ugxzg/